# I want to know the difference in performance Flutter setState

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, memory-leaks, setstate

I want to know setState the difference in order.

I write simple code below.

```
setState(() {
  _counter++;
});
```

```
_counter++;
setState(() { });
```

I think setState frequency will affect the memory leak.
I want to create a more stable version of the Flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to call setState() with the updated value because it ensures that the widget is rebuilt with the correct state. If you call setState() without passing any updated value, it may lead to inconsistencies between the widget's state and its visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

`_counter++` is increasing a counter variable this is supposedly part of the state of a **StatefulWidget**

If you do it outside of setState() function, that change will **not** be taken into account, and will not force a rebuild of the widget.

I can't say anything about a possible *memory leak*, because I know nothing about that, and I doubt this happens, because this the way of doing things. And without any more code, that's impossible to say.